Can't import all functions from custom library
I'm trying to make a custom python library that can be shared via github for the first time. I'm able to successfully install it via pip install git+repo_url, but when I try to input it into a python script, only one of the files in the library is recognized as a module. For reference this is the structure of my repo:
mylib/
    utils/
        utils.py
    __init__.py
    plot.py
    colors.py
    codes.py
    fonts.py

For some reason I can only import stuff from colors.py, but none of the other files.
When I do from mylib import colors I can access everything from colors.py, but for example from mylib import codes gives the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'codes' from 'mylib'

I've seen different suggestions about what to put in __init__.py so I've tried it both empty and with import statements for all the files and neither way worked.
UPDATE
After changing my __init__.py to contain from .module import * for all of my modules I'm now getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib.utils' from the from .plot import * in __init__.py. Currently the plot modules imports a function from utils with the from mylib.utils.utils import function. What is the correct way to do this import?

Your error ImportError: cannot import name 'fips' from 'mylib' implies you're doing something like from mylib import fips, have you included from .codes import * in your __init__.py file?

I was missing the . before the file name. fips is the same file as codes (I changed some the name to be more generic, but forgot to change the error. Now I'm getting issues with __init__.py due to imports within the files, which weren't happening when I was testing locally. What's the proper way to import utils.py in plot.p?

You need the mylib folder itself to be a Python package. Otherwise you will be forever depending on running all your things from a working directory directly above mylib - and then get some luck with its interpretation of a mylib.__init__.py,  any.
Fortunatelly, the default use case for creating a package is pretty straightforward, but very hard to find in the docs: an empty pyproject.toml file in the directory immediatelly above mylib can do it:

mylib/
    pyproject.toml  (0 bytes) (this is the git repo-root!)
    mylib/
        utils/
            utils.py
        __init__.py (0 bytes or containing "from . import plot", (one line for each script) for auto-imports)
        plot.py
        colors.py
        codes.py
        fonts.py


After doing a pip install like in the OP, this will install mylib itself as a package, and you will be able to do things like import mylib.codes.
This works due to pyproject.toml defaulting the project version to 0.0.0 and the build tool to be setuptools in the absense of any declarations. If you ever want to customize anything, search around for minimal contents for the pyproject.toml file. (In particular, it is sensible to auto-finding the code if there are any other folders in the project. You may need a [tool.setuptools] session with a packages = ["mylib"] line inside the file.
(also, renaming the utils/utils.py file to utils/__init__.py will make its contents available as mylib.utils.myutilfunc instead of mylib.utils.utils.myutilfunc)

Thanks! This helped with the other main modules, but I'm still having issues with utils. I'm still developing the package and plan to have other modules in the utils subpackage, so I'm not sure if your suggestion would work. Do you have any other ideas for how to fix it? Currently nothing in the utils folder seems to be recognized as a module.

be sure to add an __init__.py file inside utils . It can be empty, or you can repeat the strategy of doing from .utils import * (this will read all globals from the utils.py file in the same folder)  and from . import network.py (whis would make mylib.utils.network available upon importing mylib.

To make things easier to differentiate I've changed utils/utils.py to utils/functions.py. I added a utils/__init__.py file with from . import functions in it. However I'm still unable to import stuff from utils. For example in plot.py I currently have from .utils import functions, and VSCode detects the functions in functions.py, but when I try to import mylib I get an error saying No module named 'mylib.utils'.

I've resolved the issues with utils. I realized I wasn't properly including it in my setup.py.

with the pyproject.toml file there you should not need a setup.py file. (any metadata you are including in it, should go into the pyproject.toml)  - this is the new way of doing things for Python. I also like the setup.py approach - but them it should be fixed so that you don't need the  pyproject.toml.

The issue you are facing is how you're structuring your package and importing the module's __init__.py file.
When you do from mylib import colors, it works because colors.py is the top-level module in your package. However, when you try to import codes, it doesn't work because code.py is not imported into your __init__.py file.
To fix this, you need to import all the modules in your __init__.py file using the correct syntax. since you are using Python3.x, the following sample code will work __init__.py file.
from . import colors
from . import codes
from . import fonts
from . import plot
from . import utils

the dot (.) notation tells Python to import the modules from the current package.
Regarding the utils module, since it's a submodule inside the utils package you need to import it using the correct syntax. Instead of from mylib.utils.utils import function, you can try this.
from .utils.utils import function

the dot notation tells Python to look for the utils package inside the current package (mylib)
After making the above changes, you should be able to import all the modules correctly and the library should work as expected.

This definitely helped as now the functions from other modules other than colors are working, but utils still isn't. after changing the import in plot to from .utils.utils import function I still get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib.utils'. Also what would the correct way to import colors in plot?

The issue with utils is that it's a submodule inside the utils package. instead of from .utils.utils import function, try using from .utils import utils and then access the function using utils.function.
For importing colors in plot, you can use the same syntax as before from . import colors. this will import the colors module from current package (mylib).
in plot.py do something like this
from . import colors  from .utils import utils

I've changed it to that and for some reason it still isn't working. To make things easier to differentiate I've changed the name of utils/utils.py to utils/functions.py. Currently the utils/__init__.py has from . import functions and in plot.py I have from .utils import functions. The weird thing is that in plot.py VSCode detects the functions from functions.py, but when I try to import the package I still get an error from from .utils import functions saying that No module named mylib.utils.

I've resolved the issues with utils. I realized I wasn't properly including it in my setup.py.
